# puppet exec command issue

Tags: linux, puppet

Below is my puppet code ,It is killing the process in agent  but showing the error code

```
exec { "restart_process":
    command => "ps -ef | grep nrpe | grep -v pts/1 | /bin/awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9",
    path => ['/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin'],
    subscribe => File["/root/Backup/deploy"],
    refreshonly => true,
}
```

**Error code:**

```
Info: Computing checksum on file /root/Backup/deploy/nrpe.sh
Info: /Stage[main]/Myfile/File[/root/Backup/deploy/nrpe.sh]: Filebucketed /root/Backup/deploy/nrpe.sh to puppet with sum   136c6013774f5dfb84943718a70b36e0
Notice: /Stage[main]/Myfile/File[/root/Backup/deploy/nrpe.sh]/content: content 
changed '{md5}136c6013774f5dfb84943718a70b36e0' to '{md5}c4fc9099405a108923ad18f7e2db13c8'
Info: /root/Backup/deploy: Scheduling refresh of Exec[restart_process]
Error: /Stage[main]/Myfile/Exec[restart_process]: Failed to call refresh: ps -ef | grep nrpe | grep -v pts/1 | /bin/awk '{print }' | xargs kill -9 returned  instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Myfile/Exec[restart_process]: ps -ef | grep nrpe | grep -v pts/1 | /bin/awk '{print }' | xargs kill -9 returned  instead of one of [0]
Notice: Finished catalog run in 1.56 seconds
```

Can any body help me

Comment: Seems like you forget to [escape](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_data_string.html#escape-sequences) `$` symbol (look at command line in error).

Comment: ps -ef | grep nrpe | grep -v pts/1 | /bin/awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9        this command is working fine .  And puppet also killing the process but still i am getting error   due to this , puppet unable to proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

@maxd is right that you need to escape the `$` in the command when you specify it to Puppet.  This is because Puppet performs its own variable interpolation on quotation-mark-quoted strings, and this will replace the `$2` with the relevant replacement string -- probably an empty string -- before your command even reaches the catalog, and long before any attempt is made to run it.

I don't think that's your fundamental problem, however.  Your command is a shell pipeline, but the default Exec provider for your system is almost certainly `posix`, and that provider will not do what you want with the command string you provided.  You probably want to add

```
provider => 'shell'
```

to your resource, to have Puppet use the shell to execute it instead of trying to execute it directly as a (single) command.

Comment: I have changed two one is provider => 'shell' and other is /bin/awk '{print \$2}' but still same problem  <br/>                                                                                                                         exec { "restart_process":  <br/>
   path => ['/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/bin', '/usr/sbin'],<br/>
**   command => "ps -ef | grep nrpe | grep -v pts/1 | /bin/awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill -9",
**    provider => 'shell',
**    subscribe => File["/root/Backup/deploy"],
 **   refreshonly => true,
  **  }